# My simplified neural network can't learn XOR gate

Tags: matlab, neural-network, xor

I'm trying to validate the results of the book: ['Artificial Intelligence: A guide to Intelligent Systems 2nd Edition' by Michael Negnevitsky](http://www.academia.dk/BiologiskAntropologi/Epidemiologi/DataMining/Artificial_Intelligence-A_Guide_to_Intelligent_Systems.pdf), pages 181-183, on the neural network XOR gate.

The algorithm is straightforward and the book claims the NN to learn in 224 epochs or 896 iterations. It shows the first iteration calculated manually and my program calculates the same values. But here's where the similarities stop.

I can't  get it to perform anywhere near as good as shown in Figure 6.11 of the book. The network in the book (Figure 6.10) is shown in the figures below, followed by my MATLAB code.

**Network:**

[image: Network]

 <sup>***Figure 6.10*** Three-layer network for solving the Exclusive-OR operation</sup>

**Learning curve for operation Exclusive-OR:**

[image: LearningCurve]

 <sup>***Figure 6.11*** Learning curve for operation Exclusive-OR</sup>

**Code:**

```
close all; clear; clc;
alpha = 0.1; % Learning rate parameter

% Initial conditions in the book
w13 = 0.5;
w14 = 0.9;
w23 = 0.4;
w24 = 1.0;

w35 = -1.2;
w45 = 1.1;

t3 = 0.8;
t4 = -0.1;
t5 = 0.3;
cost = zeros(1,4);

X = [1 0 1 0;
     1 1 0 0];

Y = [0 1 1 0];

for epoch=1:250
    for i=1:4
        x1 = X(1,i);
        x2 = X(2,i);
        yd = Y(i);

        y3 = logsig(x1 * w13 + x2 * w23 - t3); % neuron 3 output
        y4 = logsig(x1 * w14 + x2 * w24 - t4); % neuron 4 output

        y5 = logsig(y3 * w35 + y4 * w45 - t5); % network output

        e = yd - y5; % error
        cost(epoch,i) = e^2;
        delta5 = y5 * (1 - y5) * e;

        % output neuron weight differentials
        dw35 = alpha * y3 * delta5;
        dw45 = alpha * y4 * delta5;
        dt5 = alpha * (-1) * delta5;

        delta3 = y3 * (1 - y3) * delta5 * w35;
        delta4 = y4 * (1 - y4) * delta5 * w45;
        % Hidden neuron weight differentials
        dw13 = alpha * x1 * delta3;
        dw23 = alpha * x2 * delta3;

        dt3 = alpha * (-1) * delta3;

        dw14 = alpha * x1 * delta4;
        dw24 = alpha * x2 * delta4;

        dt4 = alpha * (-1) * delta4;

        % Weight updates
        w13 = w13 + dw13;
        w14 = w14 + dw14;
        w23 = w23 + dw23;
        w24 = w24 + dw24;
        w35 = w35 + dw35;
        w45 = w45 + dw45;

        t3 = t3 + dt3;
        t4 = t4 + dt4;
        t5 = t5 + dt5;
    end
    if(sum(cost,2) < 0.001)
        break
    end
end

semilogy(1:250, sum(cost,2))
%% Test
for i=1:4
    x1 = X(1,i);
    x2 = X(2,i);
    yd = Y(i);

    y3 = logsig(x1 * w13 + x2 * w23 - t3);
    y4 = logsig(x1 * w14 + x2 * w24 - t4);

    y5 = logsig(y3 * w35 + y4 * w45 - t5);

    disp(['         YD      Y'])
    disp([yd y5])
end
```

I'm hoping someone sees what I'm doing wrong. Or, in an unlikely event, confirm that the results of the book are not possible with the information given (I doubt it, because according to what I've found, a 2-2-1 NN should be able to learn XOR easily). I just want to have a very simple 2-2-1 neural network with minimal code.

Comment: The most important part: keep on learning. I couldn't look at your code yet, but if you just do 10'000 iterations or more, it will learn the XOR function.

Comment: This is a deterministic system though. There is no random factor to it so if the book is able to get convergence in less than 250 epochs. I shouldn't have to do 10k+ epochs with the same initial conditions.

Comment: Your code looks correct to me, and it does learn the XOR after some time. One minor mistake: you need change your stopping criterion to `sum(cost(epoch,:),2) < 0.001)`, so only the error of the current epoch is considered. But this doesn't change the result.